# how to open media files from a webview into browers?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview

I have a webview which loads a webpage and it consist of some buttons to download media files such as pdf,image etc.. when i click on that the app is opens the medai files within the webview but i want to open with prompt to user with any other browser or any other apps

Comment: that will be handled on your webpage implementation , either it opens another page or direct download link

Comment: which methods should i have to override ? please excuse me i`m a beginner in ios development

Comment: webView detect links will alow you to perform what ever webpage is offering on click action

Comment: can you Please refer a link or example code please

Comment: http://conecode.com/news/2011/05/ios-tutorial-creating-a-web-view-uiwebview/   mark Detection link (point 10)